# Wireguard : ping from server to client doesn't work without adding endpoint in the peer section. What could be going wrong?

Tags: networking, ping, wireguard

I have a wireguard configuration; client is a server on digital ocean and server is somewhere else. Not in digital ocean. I have the below wireguard config for server and client:

Server side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.15.15.1/24
ListenPort = 51824
PrivateKey = ********private key of server
PostUp = ip link set wg5000 master TEST1

[Peer]
PublicKey = *******pub key of client
AllowedIPs = 10.15.15.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.15.15.2/32
ListenPort = 51824
PrivateKey = ******privaet key of client

[Peer]
Endpoint = public_ip_of_server:51824
PublicKey = *************pub key of server
AllowedIPs = 10.15.15.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Ping from client to server: ping 10.15.15.1 times out
ping from server to client: destination host unreachable.

wg show command on server:

> ```
>    interface: wg5000 
>     public key: ************************** 
>     private key: (hidden) 
>     listening port: 51824 
>     peer: ********************************** 
>     allowed ips: 10.15.15.0/24 
>     persistent keepalive: every 30 seconds
> ```

client:

> ```
> interface: wg5000   
> publickey:****************************************   
> private key: (hidden) 
> listening port: 51824 
> peer: *******************************
> endpoint:public ip of server:51824   
> allowed ips: 10.15.15.0/24
> transfer: 0 B received, 444 B sent persistent keepalive: every 30 seconds
> ```

Can any one help me understand how to make this work without adding endpoint on peer section in server?

Comment: 1) What kind of IP address is the Peer (behind a router, a NAT)? 2) Add `PersistentKeepalive = 30` to the peer to keep connections up once established.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks. Peer is a public ip. What I am trying to do is , take the 10.15.15.0/24 subnet, first IP, which is 10.15.15.1 , is taken as the wireguard interface on the server and 10.15.15.2 is taken as the wireguard interface on the client. The problem with my config is that without adding endpoint of peer in the server section, my ping doesn't work from each side. When I add the endpoint for peer in server configuration, the ping works from both sides. I don't what to add the peer endpoint in the server section.

Comment: wg show command on server:
interface: wg5000
  public key: &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51824

peer: **********************************
  allowed ips: 10.15.15.0/24
  persistent keepalive: every 30 seconds

client:
interface: wg5000
  public key: ****************************************
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51824

peer: *******************************
  endpoint: public ip of server:51824
  allowed ips: 10.15.15.0/24
  transfer: 0 B received, 444 B sent
  persistent keepalive: every 30 seconds

Comment: Add details like your last comment to the question to make reading easier.

Comment: Added. Eventhough I modified,  PersistentKeepalive = 30. The output Is the same. Cant ping from either side

Comment: Invest the time to properly edit and format your questions. Your new edit is very hard to read. Compare with the changes I made to your question. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @JohnHanley sorry about that. I have made some changes. I think It looks better now.

Comment: I dont know if this is important to your problem but in your server config I miss lines to setup your firewall to forward and masquerade the traffic: `PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <devname> s0 -j MASQUERADE` and `PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o <devname> s0 -j MASQUERADE` and perhaps your have to activate `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` too.